# Set complex constrain - Choco

Tags: java, constraints, equation-solving, choco

I have a constrain in this format:

```
(1 + x*y/z*m)*(2/x*y) - 10 = 0
```

How can I add this constraint?

*IntConstraintFactory* class provide a method called *arithm* to add simpler constraints like this one:

```
//x + y > 10
IntVar x = VariableFactory.bounded("X", 0, 5, solver);
IntVar y = VariableFactory.bounded("Y", 0, 5, solver);
IntConstraintFactory.arithm(x,"+",y,">",10)
```

but it's format is fixed.